# How do I consume a WCF webservice using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, wcf, soap

I do not have any experience with WCF but am now required to consume a WCF webservice as part of a project. I keep getting a 400 Bad Request Error

```
OPTIONS http://10.138.77.27:222/focisqmobile/Service1.svc?wsdl 400 (Bad Request)
  n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send 
  n.extend.ajax 
  WCFJSON   
  (anonymous function)  
  n.Callbacks.j 
  n.Callbacks.k.fireWith    
  n.extend.ready    
  I 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.138.77.27:222/focisqmobile/Service1.svc?wsdl. Invalid HTTP status code 400
```

My AJAX Code is as follows :

```
function WCFJSON() {


        Data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<s:Header>"+
        "<Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">http://tempuri.org/IService1/getProduct</Action>"+
    "</s:Header>"+
        "<s:Body>" +
        "<getProduct xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"/>" +
        "</s:Body>" +
        "</s:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: "http://10.138.77.27:222/focisqmobile/Service1.svc?wsdl", // Location of the service
            data: Data, //Data sent to server
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
            dataType: "xml", //Expected data format from server
            processData: true, //True or False
            success: ServiceSucceeded, //On Successfull service call
            error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
        });

    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(xml) {

        alert("Success");
        alert($.parseXML(xml));


    }

    function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
        alert("Error");
        alert($.parseXML(xhr));

    }
```

The soap message I'm using is from WCF Test Client :

[image: WCF Test Client Response]

And the WCF Test Client is able to get a response from the server.

Now, the main questions I had were :

- Do I need to change anything in the webservice to make it consumable from Javascript?
- Am I using the wrong SOAP message?
- Why is WCF Test Client able to get a response when I am unable to?
- Is the problem client side or service-side?

I have looked at a ton of online resources but I am unable to implement them.

I tried hosting the service on my own PC to avoid CORS and I still got the same error.

I already have the custom headers configured in IIS.

[image: HTTP Custom Headers]

Comment: did u try this  url: "http://10.138.77.27:222/focisqmobile/Service1.svc/getProduct insteaf of  url: "http://10.138.77.27:222/focisqmobile/Service1.svc?wsdl

Comment: u can also try this plugin for appropriate soap request as well,https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap